# Apache CXF wsdl2java when generating duplicated names inside WDSL

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I need to generate a webservice client from the axis wsdl2java client. When I wun the command:

```
wsdl2java -frontend jaxws21 -p "net.imaginary.project.ws.client" -d "D:\dev\TestClient\src" -encoding utf-8 -client https://serviceshomologa.serasaexperian.com.br/RelatoProxy?wsdl
```

it generates on the log output the following error:

```
Suppressed: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: https://servicesh
omologa.serasaexperian.com.br/RelatoProxy?xsd=xsd4 [0,0]: (Relevante para o erro
 acima) outro "ConsultarRelatoRequestType" foi gerado daqui.
                ... 7 more
```

It means when it tries to generate the ConsultarRelatoRequestType class, it is duplicated.

My webservice endpoint is:

```
https://serviceshomologa.serasaexperian.com.br/RelatoProxy?wsdl
```

The CXF documentation says I need to create a binding file, and I did, like this:

```
<bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    wsdlLocation="RelatoProxy.wsdl"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType:[@name='ConsultarRelatoRequestType']">
    <class name="ConsultarRelatoRequestType2"/>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

However when I run, the outcome is:

```
WSDLToJava Error: Could not find any node with the XPath expression: //wsdl:defi
nitions/wsdl:portType:[@name='ConsultarRelatoRequestType']
```

Because the [ConsultarRelatoRequestType] is inside the xsd and not the wsdl

Comment: Can you change the "suppressed" error message to English? Thanks!

Comment: It says ConsultarRelatoRequestType is already generated by another class.

Comment: I have successfully immported with wsimport and I am working with jax-ws. So, this is working now, but with wsdl2java seens like it needs some configuration to build the right thing.

Comment: Yes, with "Google Translate" I knew it, but it will good if you can update in your question as well.

Comment: So normally, what I did is to use the IDE built-in wizard to do that, and it is one-time thing.